# Same ruby on rails query returning different values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Can someone explain me what is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Don't put images of code/results in your question. It's impossible to copy or index properly in search engines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case, you call method `ceil` with an argument, which is `-200`, it's equivalent to:

```
(expression).ceil(-200)
```

The optional argument passed into `ceil` is responsible for precision.

In the second, you call `ceil` without any arguments and substract `200` from its result, i.e. you call method `-` with argument `200` on its result, so it's equivalent to:

```
(expression).ceil.-(200)
```